# AccessText TextWrapping not working with CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, word-wrap

I am trying to implement a `TextWrapping` feature onto the text that is displayed in a `CheckBox`. I am using the second method in [this walk through](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/02/how-to-make-text-of-checkbox-wrap.html).

I have created a completely blank program to test this. I would like to make it so that, when text inside the `checkBox` is larger than the allowed width, it moves the excess text to the next line under `checkBox`.

This is my xaml:

```
<Grid Width="100">
<CheckBox>
    <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="This is a really long sentence that needs to create a new line." ... />
</CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

The walk through uses this method to implement the result that I am looking for. Why isn't this working for me, and how do I implement it correctly?

This is what my output is:

[image]

**Updates:** `TextWrapping` changed to `"Wrap"`; Width removed; output updated

Comment: So, what's not working about what you've posted?

Comment: When I run my program the only text that is displayed in the `checkBox` is: "This is a really long".

Comment: What if you do TextWrapping="Wrap" ?

Comment: Same thing happens. I encourage you to try it.

Comment: Take off the 'Width' parameter completely.

Comment: Okay, now it displays the whole sentence, but on the same line.

Comment: The issue is because you need to limit the grid (or whatever the checkbox is in) size so your accesspanel exceeds it, causing it to wrap.

Comment: Show us the layout that contains the check box - is it a horizontal `StackPanel` or a `Grid` with an Auto column?

Comment: @XAMeLi It is a `Grid` with a set width and height. My question has been updated to show the `Grid` as well.

Comment: 384 is too wide for the text that you entered. Try copy-pasting it couple of more times to make it longer. Did it wrap? Also, you say the output is updated, but it shows all the string - am I missing something? According to the output, where is the issue?

Comment: The width has now been changed to 100. As far as the output goes, it is all displayed on one line (I would like to control when it wraps to the next line). When I said "output updated" I meant that I updated the picture in my question.

Comment: So now (after updating the width to 100) you see the text cut-off or wrapping?

Comment: It cuts off right after "needs to".